# Magento 1.4 - nginx server | 302's to Permanent 301's?

Tags: magento, nginx, url-rewriting

we have an older version of Magento (1.4) running on an nginx server. We have a few temporary redirects (302's) on the site that need to be converted to permanent 301 redirects.. There is no way to do this in 1.4 by means of the Administraton Panel :(

Can anyone provide me with the nginx configuration directives to do this?

Here is my config file for the domain:

```
    rewrite ^/minify/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/skin/m/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;

    location / {
       # First attempt to serve request as file, then
       # as directory, then fall back to index.html

       try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
       expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
    }

    location /app/                { deny all; }
    location /includes/           { deny all; }
    location /lib/                { deny all; }
    location /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
    location /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
    location /var/                { deny all; }

    location /lib/minify/ {
        allow all;
    }

    location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
        auth_basic           "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
        autoindex            on;
    }

    location  /. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
        return 404;
    }

    location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~* ^(.+\.php)(.*) {

        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;  } 
        ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
            #fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default; ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
            #fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;                                                                            
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/luxuryleathergoods.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_split_path_info      ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For each redirect, you can add the following line to your nginx configuration, inside of the `location /` block (first):

```
rewrite /old/url.html /new/url.html
```